# Closest Pair in Python

Tags: python

I am having a hard time modifying this code, I'm really new to python and I am trying to find the closest pair among the 10 input integers from a user. Here's my code so far and there is a syntax error...

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] 
a[0]=input() 
a[1]=input() 
a[2]=input() 
a[3]=input() 
a[4]=input() 
a[5]=input() 
a[6]=input() 
a[7]=input() 
a[8]=input() 
a[9]=input() 
a.sort() 
b=sorted(set(a)) 
for item in enumerate(a):
    for item1 in enumerate(b):
        c = item - enumerate(b)
        if c = item-1:
            print item
            print c
```

Thank,
Ai

Comment: You should give some example input/output of what you expect.

Comment: Can we have the stack trace, so we can see where the error does occur ?

Comment: I don't know what you think `enumerate` does, but it's not what it actually does.

Comment: I would suggest using [`itertools.permutations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=permutations#itertools.permutations) to get all the differences between all the pairs of numbers, and then find the smallest one.

Comment: Create a programming code that will accept ten integers
and will display the closest pair among the group.

sample Run

Enter 10 integers
90 5 27 63 12 47 10 150 120 48

The closest pair is 47 and 48

Answer (score 1):

Your code is causing exceptions because you're not handling the output of `enumerate` properly. Your `item` values are going to be `(value, index)` pairs, not single values, so there's no way to subtract them directly.

Here's another implementation, which may be something like what you were aiming for:

```
import itertools

def find_nearest_pair(lst):
    min_pair = None
    min_distance = float("inf")

    for a, b in itertools.combinations(lst, 2): # generates all (a,b) pairs
        distance = abs(a-b) # abs makes distance always non-negative
        if distance < min_distance:
            min_pair = (a,b)
            min_distance = distance

    return min_pair # you could return min_distance here too (or instead)
```

You could even compress it down further using the `min` function:

```
nearest_pair = min(itertools.combinations(lst, 2),
                   key=lambda item: abs(item[0]-item[1]))
```

Or if you just want the value:

```
nearest_pair_distance = min(abs(a-b) for a, b in itertools.combinations(lst, 2))
```

Comment: this one runs right once but return an error about tuples on the succeeding runs..

a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

a[0]=input()
a[1]=input()
a[2]=input()
a[3]=input()
a[4]=input()
a[5]=input()
a[6]=input()
a[7]=input()
a[8]=input()
a[9]=input()

    
a.sort()
#b=sorted(set(a))
b=a
for item in enumerate(a):
    for item1 in enumerate(b):
        c = item - item1
        if c == 1:
            print item
            print item1

@ Blckknght: I will try it. THanks :D

Comment: Thank you so much... It's running now..

'code'
import itertools

a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

a[0]=input()
a[1]=input()
a[2]=input()
a[3]=input()
a[4]=input()
a[5]=input()
a[6]=input()
a[7]=input()
a[8]=input()
a[9]=input()

    
a.sort()
b=sorted(set(a))
for item in enumerate(b):             
    c = min(itertools.combinations(b, 2),
                   key=lambda item: abs(item[0]-item[1]))

print 'The closest pair/One of the closest pair is:'
print c

Answer (score 0):

What are all these calls for `enumerate` for? That's for when you want to iterate through a collection and also keep a counter. You should remove all of them - but especially the one in the line `c = item - enumerate(b)` which makes *absolutely* no sense.

Once you've got it running, you should see you have a number of logic errors too, but I'll leave you to fix those yourself.

Comment: Thank you.. I have it running :D